# Printing output in main, not in the function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, io, void

I have a main function, which calls readNumbers to create a dynamically allocated array of length prompted by the user. Then, this array is passed to printNumbers, which prints the index of the element, followed by a space, then the corresponding element value, and then a new line.

My code is algorithmically correct, however, my teacher wants the output to be printed inside main, not inside the function. However, I am confused, because I got told that printNumbers must have a return type of void - so wouldn't this function print out stuff so that you can see this output? How could I print the output in main?

Main:

```
#include <iostream>

int * readNumbers(int n);

void printNumbers(int *numbers, int length);

int main (void)
{
    int length;

    std::cout<<"Enter your array length: "<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>length;


    int *arr=readNumbers(length);

    printNumbers(arr,length);

    delete[] arr;

    return 0;
}
```

Function file:

```
#include <iostream>

int * readNumbers(int n)
{

    int *arr=new int[n]; //array dynamically allocated

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<"Enter value: "<<"\n";
        std::cin>>*(arr +i);

    }

    return arr;



}





void printNumbers(int *numbers, int length)
{

    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<i<<" "<<*(numbers+i)<<std::endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you need to ask your teacher again what they really mean - either you print inside the `printNumbers` function, or you move the loop into `main` and ditch the `printNumbers` function entirely. It doesn't make sense to have that function, but to print inside `main`.

Comment: Simple: Replace the `printNumbers` call with the actual code used in the function.

Comment: "How could I print the output in main?" you just take that loop from function `printNumbers` and put it into `main`

Comment: Hello. But, my teacher gave me those two function signatures so I had to use them, (sorry, I should have clarified this.) In this instance, is there nothing else I could do? My teacher did not give me full marks as he said that he "did not want the output being printed in the function, but wanted it to be printed in main."

Comment: @Angela So, did you try asking your teacher for clarifications, on what he meant, when he gave you such instruction?

Comment: I did not ask for clarification at the time as I simply thought that I must have been confused on the use the void function. I can not ask for clarification anyway. He said that because of the code I have submitted, I can not receive full marks, and he will give me partial marks if I am able to fix my code without his help (partial marks as my code is algorithmically correct)...

Comment: @Angela There's a difference between asking for help, and asking for clarification of requirements.

Comment: Your teacher wants you to write a function called ”printNumbers” that *doesn’t print numbers*? Then what in the name of Dijkstra should it do? The fandango?

Comment: Bad teaching strikes again.

Comment: @molbdnilo Nicely put Sir.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand your question: value must be printed in main but function called must return `void`.

Here's one solution using an "out parameter" (I hate them, wouldn't use them normally, but given the constraints they are a reasonable option):

```
void printNumbers(int *numbers, int length, std::string &result)
{
    std::stringstream ret;
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        ret << i << " " << *(numbers+i) << std::endl;
    }
    result = ret.str();
}

int main()
{
    ...
    std::string res;
    printNumbers(arr, length, res);
    std::cout << res;
    ...
}
```

An alternative (horrible) solution would be to put the result into a global variable inside the function and then print the contents of the global variable in `main` after the function call. But please don't do that.

The *proper* solution is to have the function return its result as a `std::string` (*not* `void`) and then in `main` just print the result of the function call.